# PostgreSQL has extension 'uuid-ossp' but can't find uuid_generate_v4()

Tags: postgresql, uuid

I installed PostgreSql and checked if extention 'uuid-ossp' was there.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

And I checked the results with sql query.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions;
```

[image]

However, the `uuid_generate_v4()` function cannot be used when creating a table.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  uuid UUID NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()
);
```

Error message is below

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I'm looking for a solution to this problem. and I confirmed that superuser is executable. How can I enable the user I created to run it?

Comment: You refer to another user, but don't tell us anything about it.  How was it created?  Which of the steps you show were done as which user?

Comment: If you are on Postgres 13+ you don't need the extension for this function.There is a built in function `gen_random_uuid ()` here [UUID Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html) that does the same thing.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thank you. I was check db version. it was 9 and installed 16. it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making the user a superuser and reconnecting, the uuid_generate_v4() function can be used.

```
alter user myuser with superuser;
```

Is there any way to use it without making it a superuser?

It was version 9. and I reinstall db version 16. it works with gen_random_uuid().

Comment: Please edit the question to include these details, rather than adding your own "answer" (which simply raises another question)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe schema is not proper. Did you try to:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.my_table (
    id uuid DEFAULT public.uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
```

Comment: yes, i tried this. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the extension is installed in a schema that is not on your `search_path`. Check with

```
SELECT extnamespace::regnamespace
FROM pg_extension
WHERE extname = 'uuid-ossp';
```

You can either reference the function with the schema name or move the extension:

```
ALTER EXTENSION "uuid-ossp" SET SCHEMA public;
```

On recent PostgreSQL versions you don't need the extension. Instead, you can use `gen_random_uuid()`.

Comment: I need to find out what search_path is in postgreSQL. I'm simply using it in typeORM. That's basically using the `uuid_generate_v4()` function and not using a direct SQL query, so I can't use `gen_random_uuid()`.

Comment: You could `CREATE FUNCTION uuid_generate_v4() RETURNS uuid LANGUAGE sql AS 'SELECT gen_random_uuid()';`.

Comment: um.. but I can't excute `gen_random_uuid()` also.


CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  uuid UUID NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT gen_random_uuid()
);

result is
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function gen_random_uuid() does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: As you wrote in your own answer above, this situation can be resolved by creating a superuser. For now, it's okay to simply configure the development environment with Docker locally, but I don't think using it like this is the answer when running it on a server in the future, so I'm trying to find more solutions.

Comment: You don't need a superuser. I guess you are using a rather old version of PostgreSQL.